# Navbar change on scroll Crashes

Tags: javascript, css

I want to fade my first navbar on scroll and show my second navbar , but when using fade functions or even show() and hide() , on scroll breakpoint it keeps jumping infinitely , what should I do?

Comment: I think you should write some different code so it doesn't crash :)

Comment: it's hard to find humour on SO, but I just saw one, nice jeremy

Comment: Welcome to SO mohammad, you should post your code or what have you tried.